# The sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i!i}$

Tags: summation, factorial, gamma-function

> Evaluate $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i!i}$

**Attempt 1 - partial fractions:**
$$\frac{1}{i!i}=\frac{A}{i!}+\frac{B}{i}$$
$$1=iA+i!B$$
which is impossible without creating a denominator in $A$ which defeats the purpose.
**Attempt 2 - Gamma function:**
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i!i}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(i+1)i}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(i)}{\Gamma(i+1)^2}$$
Which isn't very promising since it isn't a beta function.

I thought about using leibnez's method or turning it into an integral but haven't managed.
If you can help, I'd like if you provided a hint and the solution in a spoiler box.
thanks!

Comment: Of course the term $i=0$ with $0$ denominator must be omitted.  Hint: Evaluate $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i!i}$ then substitute $x=1$.

Comment: We have
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{x^n}{n!n}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}
dx=\int_{0}^1\frac{e^x-1}{x}\,dx.
$$
I don't know a closed form for the integral though.

Comment: Just an idea. (In your first attempt you try splitting in form $\frac{A}{i!}+\frac{B}{i}$). What if you tried (omitting first term of summation) $\frac{A}{(i-1)!}+\frac{B}{i^2}$ ?

Comment: @Mastrem You mean $\sum_n\int_0^x\frac{e^t-1}{t}dt$, which becomes your expression when $x=1$ as required.

Comment: Note that it involves a limit of an [**exponential integral**](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralEi/06/01/03/01/) and natural logarithm. See the bolded link for the sum. We then have your integral $=\text{Ei}(1)-γ$ which is the Eulergamma/euler mascheroni constant. There are other special functions based on the link.